# Image processing with for loop (matlab)

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm new to Matlab. I am trying to compare the redness of several spots between two apples.

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
imgApple = imread('apples.tif');
figure(1), imshow(imgApple);
imgROI = imrect;

imgMask = createMask(imgROI);
imgBound = bwboundaries(imgMask);
imgXY = imgBound{1};
imgX = imgXY(:,2);
imgY = imgXY(:,1);

imgTopLine = min(imgX);
imgBotLine = max(imgX);
imgLeftCol = min(imgY);
imgRightCol = max(imgY);
imgWitdh = imgBotLine - imgTopLine + 1;
imgHeight = imgRightCol - imgLeftCol + 1;
imgCrop = imcrop(imgApple, [imgTopLine, imgLeftCol, imgWidth, imgHeight]);

redIndex = mean(mean(imgCrop(:,:,1)));
imgExcel = xlsappend('file.xls', redIndex, 'Sheet1');
```

Problem I have is that if I write it this way, I'll have to evaluate the `createMask` several times depending on how many spots I'm looking at (after shifting my ROI). I tried the `for` loop, but couldn't get it to create several masks that I can merged using:

```
newMask = imgMask;
index = (imgMask2 ~= 0);
newMask(index) = imgMask2(index);
```

From [How do I merge two masks together in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775866/how-do-i-merge-two-masks-together-in-matlab)

I am wondering if there's any way to automate the whole process using the `for` loop. Any help is appreciated and I can always clarify any doubts if I didn't explain it clearly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why merging several masks? why not getting the "redIndex" for each mask separately (then you could loop on the masks)?

Comment: I'm shifting the ROI with mouse so that ROI dimension is fixed. If I include the `imrect` into `for` loop to get "redIndex" for each mask, I'll be drawing multiple ROI with slightly different dimensions.